# iOS - SpriteKit and image dimessions

Tags: sprite-kit

I just started using SpriteKit and I am trying to put a background on my scene. I want to support iPhone 5,5S,6,6+. So I created background with dimensions(using image casset: @1x at 320x480 , @2x at 750x1334 and @3x 1242x2208.

Then I am creating a Sprite:

```
SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Backgroun.png"];

background.position=CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

[self addChild:background];
```

but the background is not covering the whole screen. What I am doing wrong here?
I found a workaround:

```
    background.size = self.frame.size;
```

but this is not right! I want to know what dimessions the background has to be for each device.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you NSlog self.size in your scene?  And is your phone in portrait or landscape?

Comment: Did you set a Launch Screen File?  I noticed it was not handling different device sizes until I set mine.

Comment: I am using this:     NSLog(@"X:%f Y:%f",CGRectGetHeight(self.frame),CGRectGetWidth(self.frame));
 and I get 768x1024 at Portrait mode. @meisenman do you mean set the image source for launch file? Because launch file is set by default